# Is Annihilation an original movie, a sequel or a remake?

Tags: sequels, remake, annihilation

I have the clear feeling and the vague memory I've seen *Annihilation* before or at least some scenes in other(s) movie(s) years ago.

Scenes I think I already seen in a movie or movies before:

- Pool with a guy with giant worms inside;
- Abandoned military base with information on a table;
- Bear attack;
- Place with people like plants;
- Beach with crystal threes;
- Suicide in front of camera using phosphorus granade;
- The hole inside the lighthouse;
- Final fight with the alien clone.

I remember to have watched something similar in TV during 90s or 2000s. But I cannot remember the name of the movie(s), almost sure of that.

Is Annihilation an original movie, a sequel or a remake?

Comment: It's based off a [book of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilation_(VanderMeer_novel)) by Jeff VanderMeer.

Comment: The giant worms inside reminds me of the scene in [_Dreamcatcher_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreamcatcher_(2003_film))

Comment: I mean, if we're allowing for the possibility that these scenes come from a variety of movies, then yeah.  These things have all happened before *somewhere*.  I don't know that they all happened in *one movie* before, though.

Comment: I think this scenes are from, at least, three different movies.

Comment: Some of the scenes could be tropes or intentional allusions, but without knowing what films, it's hard to guess.

Comment: It has a lot of parallels to the tv show Threshold.

Answer (score 12):

*Annihilation* is Alex Garland's (the director) interpretation of the first book of The Southern Reach trilogy by Jeff VanderMeer. The movie is loosely based around the book *Annihilation*. Though I'm not sure if anything else comes from the other two books as I just started the second book, *Authority*.

As for the scenes that are familiar to you, it could just be similar directors or stories. Though I am curious as to what movie you are referring to when you say there is one that contains a fight with an alien clone? This was somewhat a part of the book, but a completely different take and form in comparison to what Jeff VanderMeer wrote. It in my mind, is one of the most important scenes of the movie, as it is also a turning point in the book as well though they are very different.

Comment: It it worth noting that the book the movie is based on was first published in 2014 which makes it unlikely that that *specific* story has previously been made into a movie, though some of the themes may have appeared in other stories.

Comment: Well, scenes of interrogation are kinda from Authority. Things not form books are usually more or less random ideas of creators. While often similar to various previous works, these don't seem to be deliberate references (for ex. [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/194506/is-the-bear-monster-in-annihilation-film-a-deliberate-reference-to-alzabo-from))

Comment: There are clearly heavy influences from Lovecrafts Colour out of Space in the books and movie...